# oracle error: not enough values

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table donor_master:

```
create table donor_master  
(  
donor_id number(10) primary key not null,  
dob date not null,  
age number(3) not null,  
gender char(1) not null,  
blood_group char(3),  
contact_no number(10),  
address varchar(50) not null,  
city varchar(10) not null,  
pin number(10) not null,  
state varchar(10) not null,  
branch_registration_id number(5) references branch_master(branch_id)  
);
```

when i try to insert into the table in a procedure insert_donor_master, i  get "not enough values" error on compilation.

this is the procedure:

```
create or replace procedure insert_donor_master(  
vdob donor_master.dob%type,  
vage donor_master.age%type,  
vgender donor_master.gender%type,  
vblood_group donor_master.blood_group%type,  
vcontact_no donor_master.contact_no%type,  
vaddress donor_master.address%type,  
vcity donor_master.city%type,  
vpin donor_master.pin%type,  
vstate donor_master.state%type,  
vbranch_registration_id donor_master.branch_registration_id%type  
)  
is  

begin  

    insert into donor_master values (sq_donor_master.nextval, vdob, vage, vgender, vblood_group, vcontact_no, vaddress, vcity, vpin, vstate, vbranch_registration_id);  
    commit;  

end;
```

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: in your create or replace procedure you didn't mention about donor_id??

Comment: yes, because i am using sequence to insert the donor_id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle hurls ORA-00947 when we specify an INSERT statement which doesn't have a value for every column in the table.

Now, the CREATE TABLE statement you posted shows a table with eleven columns.  And the stored procedure code you posted shows an insert statement with eleven values in the VALUES (...) clause.

So, the explanations are:

1. you have a configuration management issue, and you're running the wrong version of the stored procedure or the wrong version of the table
2. you have a configuration management issue, and the actual structure of the table isn't what you think it is (doesn't match your CREATE TABLE script)
3. you aren't really getting an ORA-00947 error

Note that if you don't want to populate every row you can specify a projection of the relevant columns before the VALUES clause.  For instance, if you just wanted to populate the mandatory columns you would code this:

```
insert into  donor_master 
    (donor_id, dob, age, gender, address, city, pin, state )
   values (sq_donor_master.nextval, vdob, vage, vgender, vaddress, vcity, vpin, vstate)
```

All that matters is that the number of values matches the number of columns.

The complete syntax for INSERT statements is in the documentation.  [enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#i2163698)Find out more.

Comment: Just now, i tried mentioning the column names before the 'values' in the insert statement above and to my surprise it compiled. But when i remove the list of column names it again gives the error.

Comment: @Neal: then check your table's actual structure.

Comment: @Mat: you were right Mat, the actual table structure had one more column. Should always had trusted on 'desc' rather than the create table code. guess somebody had added a column and didnot change the create table statement. I cannot accept a comment as an answer, so what should i do?

Comment: @Neal - as I suggested in my answer this is a config mgmt issue: the actual table structure didn't match the version of the code you posted. So accept my answer :)